# I'm worried I'm adding too many interfaces

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am building out my domain model and continuing to refactor it.  As I do, I am finding that I like interfaces as it allows me to create reusable methods/controllers/views for concrete types based on their interfaces.  However, I am finding that I am creating an interface every time I add a new property to one of my domain entities.

For example, I have a **MemberStatus** object which inherits from an abstract **Entity** object which in turn implements the **IIdentifiableEntity** interface meaning that it has an Id property.  MemberStatus also implements the **INamedEntity** interface meaning that it has a Name property, the **IOrderedEntity** interface meaning that it has a DisplayOrder property and the **IHasMembers** interface meaning that it has a collection Member objects.  Here's the code:

```
public class MemberStatus : Entity, INamedEntity, IOrderedEntity, IHasMembers
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public float DisplayOrder { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IIdentifiableEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IIdentifiableEntity
{
  int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface INamedEntity
{
  string Name { get; set; } 
}

public interface IOrderedEntity
{
  float DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasMembers
{
  ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this seems to work fine as I other similar objects such as **MemberPosition** and **MemberTeam** which all implement these same interfaces and I can use my repository methods and controller actions with generics that implement these interfaces and have a lot of code reuse.

However, my concern is whether or not it's appropriate to keep adding simple, one-property interfaces every time I add a new property to my concrete objects.  For example, let's say I want to add a `bool Enabled` property... should I continue to create a **IEnabled** interface?  The reason I'm asking is that some of controller "initializers" that are using generics are becoming very long as shown in the following line of code.  Is this normal and best-practice?

```
public abstract class OrderedCrudController<TEntity> : CrudController<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, INamedEntity, IOrderedEntity, IHasMembers, new()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fact that you are using interfaces is a good thing. However, you should ask yourself, if I create an `IEnabled` interface, will I ever reference my class by that interface alone? i.e. will there be contexts where I interact with my class purely via the single property that interface exposes?

Also, can you consider contexts where you will interact with multiple implementation of this `IEnabled` interface?

If the answer to both of these question is "no", then the interface serves very little purpose.

Having said that, please don't worry too much about this! it does very little harm.

Comment: Thank you Colin.  Quick question... would it be more appropriate for me to create an abstract class called something like **MemberPropertyEntity** (that implements the same interfaces as I show above for MemberStatus) that then MemberStatus, MemberPosition, MemberTeam all inherit from (and therefore would have almost no code in them directly)?  My controller initializer would then only need to have a `where TEntity : MemberPropertyEntity clause`. Is this better than having controllers with a bunch of interface requirements?

Comment: @bmccleary Sure - it is a relatively common pattern to have interfaces that are common to all entities, such as IHavePrimaryKey - but implement this interface in an abstract base-class. However, my original point still stands regarding interfaces such as IEnabled, if you never refer to types by that interface alone, it is of little use.

Answer (score 19):

Don't create interfaces that you don't foresee an imminent need for. Observe the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) (you ain't gonna need it) principle. Otherwise you'll wind up with needlessly complicated code.

Comment: Thanks... sometimes it's good to remember not to over complicate things.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you are trying to shoe-horn your domain model into whatever gui that you're displaying data in.

Instead, consider your domain object things that have behaviour close to data and in its c'tor, give it an `Action<DomainEvent>`. Now, make sure that you ONLY EVER pass data OUT from a domain object through this action.

Now, you listen. Whenever you *actually* want to make a change to your domain, call a method on it. Let your GUI be updated through the `Action<DomainEvent>` by taking these events and saving them to whatever read model that you are interested in.

Have a look at http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-eric-evans and consider his points about domain events.

Now you don't have to add strange interfaces related to a technical domain into your business domain anymore. And remember; if you are doing CRUD like your examples show, then you are NOT doing domain driven design. You have an anemic domain.

Final point: use interfaces for things that actually need to be interchangeable. Are you carrying around a lot of `INamed` things in your application that can be interchanged with one another?

Let me also link this, for you to consider:

- http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/10/11/event-sourcing-as-a-strategic-advantage/
- http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/

Comment: thanks for the information.  It give me quite a bit to read up on.  I've never studied DDD, so I will see what it all entails and use your links for reference.