# Common Interfaces for MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, interface

hi could anybody tell me if i miss some usefull interface? and there are disadvantages?

**for the Model:**

- `IEditableObject`
- `IClonable`
- `INotifyPropertyChanging`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` if there are some Model updates from the backend
- ???

**for the ViewModel:**

- `INotifyPropertyChanging`
- `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- `IDataErrorInfo`
- `IDisposable`
- ???

**for the View:**

- ??? (i heard about a `IView (DataContext {set;})`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have all the common interfaces that the framework itself provides. These should enough for you to become an MVVM ninja!

If you need anything else, I would recommend creating your own interfaces as and when you need them.

Regarding interfaces in general, see this related question that I answered:

[I'm worried I'm adding too many interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944229/im-worried-im-adding-too-many-interfaces)

> If I create an `IView` interface, will I ever reference my class by
>   that interface alone? i.e. will there be contexts where I interact
>   with my class purely via the single property that interface exposes?
>
> Also, can you consider contexts where you will interact with multiple
>   implementation of this `IView` interface?
>
> If the answer to both of these question is "no", then the interface
>   serves very little purpose.

Comment: Agree to that. In special the viewmodel should have its own interface, so it could be changed for example for some design data or tests

Comment: what do you thing about the `IView` Interface is this usefull ?

Comment: @Boas Enkler could you provide some example please?

Comment: I Mean if you have for example a viewmodel MyModel with a Method Foo. You should create an Interface IMyModel with that method. so that when someelse references your viewmodel he could yuse the interface and does not rely on a specific viewmodel type

Comment: @BoasEnkler see my updated answer, you shouldn't just create interfaces for the sake of them! An interface with a single, non-interchangeable implementation serves no purpose!

Comment: Yes your right. but at least with designTimeData and / or tests on the view you have the required pupose :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a common practice to create RelayCommand in MVVM (ViewModel), where you will have to implement ICommand.

Comment: thanks but i only want to know for the Model, ViewModle and View